# internet explorer 11 bold font issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Morning people,

This may be a silly question - I expect the answer is probably quite simple and I have just overcomplicated it - but one of my colleagues has managed to set all of her IE11 text as bold.

Each website shows every bit of text emboldened, but other applications are fine. Originally I wondered if she had simply set the font larger but I have checked in setting and fonts and even pressed F10 > View > Text Size. Even the display settings in Windows control panel show everything to be normal.

My colleague thinks she may have accidentally pressed the wrong shortcut on her keyboard but I can't think what it could be. The zoom setting is also at 100% before that is mentioned!...

Thanks for your help

Comment: I know of a similar issue that affected IE9 sometime ago & microsoft released an update to fix, have you tried a windows update to see if all drivers / fonts etc are up to date?

Comment: Is it just in ie or other browsers too? It could be something to do with the default font or accessibility settings (both in the general tab in settings)

Comment: thank you both for your responses, i believe all the updates are automatic in our work place but I'll ask the user to check update and try out a different web browser such as chrome. i'll let you know if we have any joy

Comment: right, the problem is not occurring in Chrome and the users IE11 version is the same as mine. It was working fine previously also! I am a bit baffled as to what the problem is. I've checked through the font and accessibility settings, even had a peek in the advanced tab under Internet Options and cannot see anything different to my set up.

Comment: Internet Options>General tab>Fonts button.... check that she is using the same default-font families as you.....some foreign language fonts have strong weightings.
Internet Options>General tab>Accessibility tab, uncheck "Use UserStylesheet"
I suppose you have already tested in noAddons Mode?
Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff [url]